# ALINK: error AL1037: Unable to find the entry point method

Tags: .net, linker, .net-assembly

I am trying to build an executable from two .Net modules:

```
al elevate-common.netmodule elevate-exe.netmodule /target:exe /out:elevate.exe /main:net.kolotyluk.windows.elevate.Elevate.main
```

But I get

```
ALINK: error AL1037: Unable to find the entry point method 'net.kolotyluk.windows.elevate.Elevate.main'
```

My source code is

```
namespace net.kolotyluk.windows.elevate
{
    public class Elevate
    {
        public static int Main(string[] commandArguments)
        {
```

is there something obvious I am doing wrong?

Do the modules have to be somewhere else than the current directory?

Answer (score 0):

Doh, wrong platform. In .Net the entry point is .Main with a capital M, whereas in Java it is lower case by default.